# Deployed Java application says "Not a valid 32 application" on windows 7 64-bit OS using 32-bit libraries

Tags: java, exe, compatibility, 32-bit

I've created EXE using NetBeans 8.2 32-bit installer and I've used 32-bit JDK on windows 7 64-bit.
So why I'm getting error:

> Not a valid 32 application on windows xp 32-bit?